# Cloudwatch alarm for Autoscaling with condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

How to setup cloudwatch alarm for Autoscaling group when its scaled upto a particular number of Instances?

Suppose, the maximum number of instances is 6. I need to get notified when the no: of instances crossed 3.

Answer (score 1):

There is a metric called GroupTotalIsntances accessible via CloudWatch Console > Metrics > Auto Scaling > Group Metrics which gives you the total number of instances in your ASG. Create a new alarm and use this metric. Read more [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-monitoring.html).

Comment: Thank you. That's what I exactly needed.